# Problem in using printf() function instead of cout

Tags: c, printf, c++17

I was trying to solve [the record breaking day problem from kickstart](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff08/0000000000387171#problem).

I have two questions:

1. Why the `printf` function is not working but the `cout` does the job (which means there is no problem with the logic)
2. Why the code is not passing the test case 1 given in the kickstart.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long solve(){
    long long n;
    cin >>n;
    long long a[n];
    for(long long j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>a[j];
    long long k=0,ans=0;
    for(long long j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        if(a[j]>k){
            k=a[j];
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a[n-1]>k)
        ans++;
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    long long t;
    cin >> t;
    for(long long i=1;i<=t;i++){
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n",i,solve());//instead of printf() this works: cout<<"Case #"<<i<<": "<<solve()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample test case from kickstart:

```
4
8
1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0
6
4 8 15 16 23 42
9
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5
6
9 9 9 9 9 9
```

output with printf():

```
Case #1: 0
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 0
Case #4: 0
```

expected output(output that i get with cout):

```
Case #1: 2
Case #2: 1
Case #3: 3
Case #4: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` format code `%d` expects an `int` not a `long long`.

The max value for an `int` is 2,147,483,647 and is probably big enough for your usage.

---

The reason that `cout` is working is because [`std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is overloaded to understand `long long` values.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int` but you're passing in a `long long`.  Using the wrong format specifier triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To print a `long long`, you need to use `%lld`.

Using the `<<` operator on `cout` has overloads for various parameter types so it knows the type based on the chosen overload.